# Node writes files with an encoding unrecognised by Sublime Text

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

When writing files with Node's fs's [`writeFileSync`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_filename_data_options) command, Sublime Text is unable to determine the correct character encoding.

Even when I explicitly define the encoding in the options:

```
fs.writeFileSync( '/path/to/file', 'some string', {encoding:'utf-8'});
```

In order to encode it as UTF-8, I have to `File > Save with Encoding` in Sublime to get it to recognise the correct encoding.

My hunch is that the problem is with Node, not Sublime, as I have encoding issues reading the file back into Node when special characters are present.

I'm using Sublime Text Build 3065.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

**EDIT**

Apologies, I forgot to mention that I use this command in the Sublime Text console in order to determine the encoding of the file:

```
view.encoding() // 'Undefined'
```

Comment: seems to be fine in my sublime build. you can use `show_encoding: true` in settings-user to see in which encoding sublime text is opening the file

Comment: maybe u can set  `default_encoding` or `fallback_encoding` to utf-8 in `settings - user` and try to reopen the file. Seems like sth with sublime. Does the file open correctly with other editors?

Comment: Try opening a bunch of other files, and see what `view.encoding()` shows. My bet is that they'll be `Undefined` as well. Operating systems define the default encoding for files, so the files themselves don't necessarily need to be saved with a particular encoding.